# Excel VBA Copy and Paste Loop within Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I’ve been working on this VBA code for a while and since I’m a complete noob I feel like I haven’t gotten anywhere. I’ve been researching a ton, but can’t seem to combine answers to help with my scenario.

Essentially what I’m trying to do is grab data, line by line, from one worksheet and extrapolate it to another worksheet. I believe this will involve loops and I’m so new with VBA I don’t know how to do it.

Here’s the logic I’m attempting:
For each row on worksheet 1, I would like to perform 3 different copy and paste activities to worksheet 2 and then it will loop down to the next row on sheet1 and do the 3 activities and so on. This will continue downwards until column A is blank in sheet1. Sheet1 data starts at A3 and sheets2 paste area starts at A2.

The first activity is to copy cells F3,D3,A3, and H3 (in that order so F3 will be A2, D3 will be B2 etc) from sheet 1 to sheet 2 to A2,B2,C2, etc. A destination functions can’t be used because I need just the values and no other formats—one of the many issues I’ve ran in to.

The next activity is to copy cells F3,D3,A3 and I3 from sheet 1 to sheet2  pasted below the previous copy and paste—again no formats just values. Also to note, some of these may be blank (except A column) but I still need that row there with at least column A data—this goes to say with all these activities.

The third activity is to copy and paste sheet1’s F3,D3, and A3 a certain number of times referencing K3’s number—and each copy and paste will be in the next available blank cell. So if the number in K3 it will look like it created 3 rows in sheet2—totaling 5 rows on sheet2 since activity1 and 2 each create their own row.

After these three activities are completed for row 3 on sheet 1, it will then move to row 4 and do the previous three activities and paste to sheet2. And again it will be pasting no formats and in the next blank row on sheet 2. Also again, this loop will stop once the cell in Column A is blank.

Below is my incomplete code. I don’t even think it will help one bit and it would probably be better not to even look at it. I’ve just started to get frustrated since I can’t even do a simple copy and paste, yet alone loops within loops. I also haven’t even started on my third activity. I greatly appreciate it!

```
Sub copyTest3()

Dim proj As Range, release As Range, pm As Range, lead As Range, coord As Range
Dim leadCopy As Range, coordCopy As Range
Dim i As Range

Set proj = Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown))
Set release = Range("D3", Range("D3").End(xlDown))
Set pm = Range("F3", Range("F3").End(xlDown))
Set lead = Range("H3", Range("H3").End(xlDown))
Set coord = Range("I3", Range("I3").End(xlDown))

Set leadCopy = Union(pm, release, proj, lead)
Set coordCopy = Union(pm, release, proj, coord)


For i = 1 To Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A3"), ActiveSheet.Range("A3").End(xlDown))
    leadCopy.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    coordCopy.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: what you are asking is doable. But before I try something let me ask this. There doesn't appear to be any logic (i.e. only paste if x condition is true). If that is the case, can you just paste the entire column (in the desired order, instead of going row by row? This will be much faster than the loops.

Comment: That's correct there isn't any logic to paste...except my third activity will look at column "k" and figure out how many times to copy and paste essentially how many new rows will be in sheet 2. I don't think doing columns will work, because the destination sheet will have many repeat names in each column. Its important to note that activity two will be pasting on sheet2 A-D, just like activity 1---which is why each needs their own row in sheet2. Does this answer your quesiton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, and some are more efficient than others. My solution may not be the most efficient, but hopefully it will be easy for you to understand so that you can learn.

It's very difficult to understand what you're attempting to do in activity three, so I wasn't able to provide a solution to that step. Use my code as a template for step three and if you run into issues, feel free to leave a comment.

Notice that I don't use `.Activate`, `.Select`, or `.Copy` in this code. `.Activate` and `.Select` are huge efficiency killers, and they make it easier for your code to "break," so avoid using them when possible. `.Copy` isn't necessary when working with values or formulas and will also slow your code down.

**Untested**

```
Sub testLoopPaste()

Dim i As Long
Dim ii As Long
Dim i3 as Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

'Find the last row (in column A) with data.
LastRow = sht1.Range("A:A").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
ii = 2

'This is the beginning of the loop
For i = 3 To LastRow
    'First activity
    sht2.Range("A" & ii) = sht1.Range("F" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("B" & ii) = sht1.Range("D" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("C" & ii) = sht1.Range("A" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("D" & ii) = sht1.Range("H" & i).Value
    ii = ii + 1

    'Second activity
    sht2.Range("A" & ii) = sht1.Range("F" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("B" & ii) = sht1.Range("D" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("C" & ii) = sht1.Range("A" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("D" & ii) = sht1.Range("I" & i).Value
    ii = ii + 1

    'Third activity
    For i3 = 1 To sht1.Range("K" & I)  
        sht2.Range("A" & ii) = sht1.Range("F" & i).Value  
        sht2.Range("B" & ii) = sht1.Range("D" & i).Value  
        sht2.Range("C" & ii) = sht1.Range("A" & i).Value  
        ii = ii + 1  
    Next i3

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this is definitely what I'm trying to do! The third activity will look at each column K and repeat a copy and paste of F,D, and A to sheet2 to A,B, and C depending on what number is in column K. I'm not entirely sure how to do that :-/

Comment: See my updated code. I added Activity Three. The third activity is essentially another loop that loops according to the number in column K. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: That is it exactly! You don't know how much time I tried to do that! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi ARich, I tried to send a message to you, but I guess there isn't a way to do that. I don't want to bother you anymore, but I was curious if you could explain a little more about how that code works. I understand the Dims and Set, but I could use some more explanation about the ii = 2, and why the For i = 3, and ii = ii + 1, etc. I just don't really get the loop part and how the ii, i and i3 specifically work...

Comment: No worries. Notice how each of those variables are declared `As Long`. In this particular case, I use those three variables as counters. For example, you wanted the loop to start on the third row, so I start the counter `i` at 3 (`For i = 3`). The next counter needed to start on the second row, so `ii = 2`, and then when we needed to go to the next row, `ii = ii + 1`. The last loop starts at 1 (`For i3 = 1) and needed to end at the value in K. [Read this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx) for more info on variables.

Comment: Hey ARich, now I'm trying to get this to be more advanced. Instead of having it copy over every item (to LastRow) from sheet 1 to sheet2. Is there a way I can use a UserForm to copy over specific ones and have it paste at the last used row of sheet 2? Does this make sense? I can get the userform to populate each row, however I'm unsure of what the button click code should be.

Comment: Hi @blasibr There probably is a way to do what you're wanting. It sounds like you've already started working on the code. If you're at a point where you've hit a wall, I suggest researching/asking another question since you'll likely get a more well-rounded answer than one I can provide in comments. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually approach copying data between sheets in Excel is to create source range and destination range objects, each range referring to just one row. When I want to move on to the next row, I use [`Offset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff840060.aspx) to return a range offset to the next row.

Since the ranges only refer to one row, you can index them with an integer to get the cells in the row. E.g. if `cursor` refers to columns A through D in row 3, `cursor(3)` will give you the cell C3.

```
Dim src_cursor As Range
Dim dest_cursor As Range

Set src_cursor = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:I3")
Set dest_cursor = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:D2")

'' Loop until column A is empty in source data
Do Until IsEmpty(src_cursor(1))
    dest_cursor(1) = src_cursor(6) '' copy F -> A
    dest_cursor(2) = src_cursor(4) '' copy D -> B
    '' and so on

    '' move cursors to next row
    Set src_cursor = src_cursor.Offset(1, 0)
    Set dest_cursor = dest_cursor.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
```

Also, this might be getting a little off topic, but it's a better practice to use an [`Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/gg251516.aspx) to name the column numbers instead of hardcoding them like I did here.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It's still good to see better ways of writing code than my own!