# Excel VBA - Loop through column one at a time

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach, nested-loops

I am trying to loop through each row in `Sht1 (B2:B138)`, and set an "input" cell `Sht2 (A1)` to each item in that loop, one at a time.  Then, the value in an "output" cell `Sht2 (N7)` would be copied back to `Sht1 (C2:C138)`.

---

So for example:

`Sht2 (A1) = value in Sht1 (B2)`, then
`Sht1 (C2) = value in Sht2 (N7)`

Repeat

`Sht2 (A1) = value in Sht1 (B3)`, then
`Sht1 (C3) = value in Sht2 (N7)`

---

Over and over until it reaches the bottom of the list.  Eventually I may have to expand the list in `Sht1 ColB` and so I have been trying to have it evaluate the number of iterations needed dynamically.

The code I'm trying below gives me all the correct "outputs" but they do not end up in the correct cell in `Sht2 ColC`. Please see below.  I researched and found [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805874/excel-vba-copy-and-paste-loop-within-loop) to be helpful and used it to influence the code.  I appreciate your help in advance.  [My workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B38YKIZO_lcKVW5FNVBMa2hibzA/view?usp=sharing) in case you need to see it.

```
Sub fnDescCalc()
'Define the objects

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Framework As Worksheet
Dim SumFramework As Worksheet
Dim colB As Long
Dim colC As Long
Dim LastcolC As Integer
Dim LastcolB As Long

'Set the Variables
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Framework = wb.Sheets("Framework")
Set SumFramework = wb.Sheets("Sum_Framework")

LastRowcb = Framework.Range("B:B").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
colB = 2

LastcolC = 138

'This is the beginning of the main loop
For colC = 2 To LastcolC

'This is the beginning of the nested loop
    For colB = 2 To LastcolB
    SumFramework.Range("A1") = Framework.Range("B" & colB).Value
    colB = colB + 1

Framework.Range("C" & colC) = SumFramework.Range("N7").Value
colC = colC + 1

Next colB

Next colC

End Sub
```

Comment: "The outputs are not in the correct places" - where do the outputs end up? Where did you expect them to end up? Have you run through your code line by line [using F8], hovering over your variables to see if they turn into something you wouldn't have expected?

Comment: I guess what i mean is that if Sht1 B2 goes into the "input" cell then the value from the "output" cell would be pasted right next to B2 in C2.  But when i run it this is not the case, they are all pasted in colC but it appears to be random.  I will upload my file and try your F8 suggestion.

Comment: okay I linked to the main workbook file above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation and the code you provided don't really match. So I understood you want to do the following:

You enter 2 Values. A search-value (SumFramework.Range("A1")) and an input-value (SumFramework.Range("N7")). Now every item in the List in column B of Sheet "Framework" that matches the search-value gets assigned the input-value in column C. If I am wrong in my understanding please elaborate :)

1.
In your code LastcolB never gets initialized so it will be 0 and the loop will never execute.

2.
You only need one loop to do what [Edit: you described in your comment]:

```
MaxRow = Framework.Range("B:B").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
'Alternative if the last row is the actual last row and .Row < 1000:
'MaxRow = Framework.Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Row


For rowB = 2 To MaxRow
    SumFramework.Range("A1") = Framework.Range("B" & rowB).Value
    Framework.Range("C" & rowB) = SumFramework.Range("N7").Value
Next rowB
```

3. "For...Next" counts automatically up. With `colB = colB + 1` you skip every section row.

Comment: The values in column B are static, they are types of activities that the operation could be doing at any moment, and each item in that static list need to be entered into SumFramework.Range("A1").  This is the only input.  Excel calculates the output, which are total hours spent performing that activity, in SumFramework.Range("N7").  Then I would like for that number of total hours to be put into the column next to its corresponding activity.  So then i would end up with a list of activities and right next to it a list of how many hours was spent doing those activities.

Comment: Ah ok. And in the first 138 rows the values are unique and after that they can appear again? (Otherwise I don't see why you would need two loops)

Comment: From researching it looks like i would need to do something (copy it to the input cell) for each value in the B2:B138 and then do something (receive each unique output) for each cell in C2:C138.

Comment: I edited my answer. Is this how you meant it? The process is quite easy Take Value from Column B --> Copy to "A1" --> "N7" gets calculated --> Copy "N7" in the same row to Column B.

Comment: thank you be_kehrer! Tested your solution and it works perfectly.