# Excel vba copy and paste loop within loop - limit range

Tags: vba, excel

Newbee here to both this site and Excel VBA. I used RichA's code in the below post and was able to make it work well for my purpose of populating/copying data in on sheet (Sheet2) from another sheet.

CODE LINK TO ORIGINAL POST
[Excel VBA Copy and Paste Loop within Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805874/excel-vba-copy-and-paste-loop-within-loop?rq=1)

I have a question on how to limit the range to a 'named range' (C13:Z111) rather than the 'entire column' ("C") in this code. I cannot seem to get it to limit to copy rows, starting with last row with data and counting down to the first row.

I have some rows (C1:C12) with titles at the top and the data starts at row 13. So when copying values from one sheet to the 'other' sheet, the top rows also copy. I would like to end the copying of data at row 13.

Thank you for your help.

Here is what currently works with the exception that I am not able to limit the range.

```
Sub Generate_Invoice()

Dim i As Long
Dim ii As Long
Dim i3 As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("INCENTIVE")
Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("B11:Z200").ClearContents

'Find the last row (in column C) with data.
LastRow = sht1.Range("C13:C111").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
ii = 2

'This is the beginning of the loop >>>This Works BUT BUT BUT goes all the way to the top - REQUESTING HELP WITH CODE ENDS AT ROW 13 AND DOES NOT GO PAST<<<

For i = 3 To LastRow
    'First activity
    sht2.Range("B" & ii) = sht1.Range("C" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("C" & ii) = sht1.Range("G" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("D" & ii) = sht1.Range("H" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("E" & ii) = sht1.Range("P" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("F" & ii) = sht1.Range("R" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("G" & ii) = sht1.Range("AD" & i).Value

    ii = ii + 1

Next i

'Return to "Sheet2"
Sheets("Sheet2").Select

'Add SUM at bottom of last record in Range"D"
 Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R11C6:R[-1]C6)"
            .Offset(, -1).Value = "Total:"
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Change `For i = 3 to LastRow` to `For i = 13 to LastRow` or change `ii=2` to 'ii=13`...  not exactly which one at the point, because I am a little confused.

Answer (score 2):

You were looking for the last row but only looking within the populated area. I would suggest changing the method that the last row is determined by starting at the bottom of the worksheet and finding the last populated cell in column C. This would be like being in C1048576 and tapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>▲</kbd>.

```
'Find the last row (in column C) with data.
LastRow = sht1.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

'not sure whether you want to reverse this as well
ii = 2

'This is the beginning of the loop >>>This Works BUT BUT BUT goes all the way to the top - REQUESTING HELP WITH CODE ENDS AT ROW 13 AND DOES NOT GO PAST<<<

For i = LastRow To 13 Step -1   'work from the bottom to the top.
    'First activity
    sht2.Range("B" & ii) = sht1.Range("C" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("C" & ii) = sht1.Range("G" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("D" & ii) = sht1.Range("H" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("E" & ii) = sht1.Range("P" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("F" & ii) = sht1.Range("R" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("G" & ii) = sht1.Range("AD" & i).Value

    'not sure whether you want to reverse this as well
    ii = ii + 1

Next i
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer--very much appreciated. When implementing these changes the data is copied in reverse order. Sheet2 shows rows starting with the last record first and the first record last. Also rows with blanks in the C column are now copied. The data is still written into rows 1-13. I am trying to not copy rows in rows 1-13 and start the copying effective row 13 rather than starting at row 1, Reason, titles and instructions are located in row 1-13.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to exit the `for` loop based on whatever your desired criteria is. For example:

```
If ii = 13 Then Exit For
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. This change stops at row 13 and thus in the scope of the code only shows one record since we are copying within that range.